# Google sheets subquery in where claus

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Is there a way to pass the result of a query in another query in Google Sheets?

**My use case example**

=QUERY(form;"select * where D like ***here is where i need my result of another query***";1)")"

the other query --> QUERY(another_range;"select * ";0)

[image: check image for an example]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for your answer Calculuswhiz. I have added an image to make it as easier as it gets

Comment: See if this works: `=QUERY(testForm;"select A where A=date'"&Text(G2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")`. G2 is the result date, Change `A` to whatever your column is.

Comment: I get an error...No need to use date function as i use text format

Comment: I should have thought about it first.. here is your link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HNBL2KRwZdvQmqZqm-ERwdQsXeSFY8Ek5MTE3CYEvLw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok, then, it's simple string concatenation then. No need for the `like` since you're not pattern matching. `=query(testForm,"select * where B='"&G3&"'",1)`

Comment: God bless you Calculuswhiz...you saved my life...i was mistyping the concatenation formula!! Is there a way to add this result as subquery? for example getting the G2 cell value from a query like select * where B = "select * where....

Comment: Sort of... but not directly in the query string. What I mean is that you'll have to replace G3 with another formula that gets the date. In other words, you are concatenating another `Query` formula.

Comment: Great i'll give it shot myself and keep you updated...thanks for your time

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: Sheet is live again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY(B2:D; "where B = date '"&TEXT(G2; "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"; 1)
```

or if you want it hardcoded:

```
=QUERY(B2:D; "where B = date '2021-02-10'"; 1)
```

Comment: Thanks player0...First works fine...Second returns blank...